# how to get the top 10 popular blogs

Tags: plugin-development, comments, query-posts, users

Our wordpress sites have `many many users`, each of them have an blog account, they can write posts,comments and so on.

Now I want to find out `the top 10 popular blogs`, according to or order by `comments`, or `blog visite number`, or manybe `some other stands`.

Yes, I can find out the most 10 comments of the posts, but can I get the blogs? A litter difficult.

Anyone could you please show me some ideas, thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you be more precise please? Is is a multisite installation?

Comment: @JMa No, I just install one wordpress, but I create many many user in wp_users, they using their own username add password logon the system, and writes posts ...

Comment: ok so you just need to know popular posts which is not difficult.

Comment: @JMa thanks man, not popular posts, get the popular posts is easy, I want to get the popular blog, for example, even one of blogger's post is popular, but his blog may not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like this should help you.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_author, SUM(comment_count) as comments FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' GROUP BY post_author ORDER BY comments DESC LIMIT 10");
```

This will return you 10 authors of most commented posts (with highest sum of comments count of each post they have written).

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted though.